# Kendo grid change event doesn't fire upon casperJS click

Tags: kendo-ui, casperjs, kendo-grid

I have a bit of an obscure problem that I'm finding hard to track down with the Kendo Grid. Through a browser I can click a row and it is selected fine with the change event firing. However, if I click the `tr` or `td` element using casperJS:

```
casper.thenClick('#id-of-the-grid tr:nth-child(2)', function () {
    this.capture('gridSelect.png');
});
```

I get nothing highlighted on the captured photo. I have tried firing a mousedown followed by a mouseup command, a click command, all sorts of variations but I am still unable to fire the Kendo Grid `change` event. Am I wrong in thinking that the `change` event is fired by a mouseup? Am I clicking the wrong element and Kendo Grid is responding to a different elements click event?

Comment: I don't think the Kendo Grid handles it like that at all.  The change event is fired when actual underlying data is changed in the control.

Comment: Well it does respond to a mouseup event in the browser normally (I initially had the same thoughts as you).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Try to work out how to click a tab strip. thanks

Comment: Nope, used Selenium instead.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. This solution seems to work for me. I adapted the example hope this works for you.

What I did was first I fire a ***mousedown***, ***click*** and then the ***mouseup*** event on the specific element.

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.mouseEvent('mousedown', '#id-of-the-grid tr:nth-child(2)');
    this.mouseEvent('click', '#id-of-the-grid tr:nth-child(2)');
    this.mouseEvent('mouseup', '#id-of-the-grid tr:nth-child(2)');
}

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('gridSelect.png');
}
```